# gnome-flashback panels not starting in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: compiz, 14.04, gnome-panel

After upgrading to 14.04 LTS, my gnome-flashback session starts, but without the top and bottom panels.

Logging with compiz, I can use CTRL+SHIFT+T to start a terminal and run "gnome-panel", which starts both panels. I'm using this workaround, but it is very annoying to login without the panels.

.xession-errors shows nothing related to gnome-flahback, just stuff like this:

init: indicator-bluetooth main process ended, respawning
init: indicator-bluetooth respawning too fast, stopped

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

**Delete `$HOME/.local/share/applications/gnome-panel.desktop`**

For some reason the old system copied its `gnome-panel.desktop` to your own `$XDG_DATA_HOME` (by default on `.local/share`). After the upgrade, `/usr/share/applications/gnome-panel.desktop` (belonging to *gnome-panel* package) was updated, but not the copy, which still has the old contents and is thus shadowing the global file (per the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)).

As the old file is incompatible with the new version (which seems a bug), gnome-panel is not started.

Just by deleting this copy, the /usr/share instance will be found, properly launching  gnome-panel without having to run it by other means.

In case you prefer to fix the existing file instead of removing it (although there's nothing important there), open with a text editor and:

- Change `OnlyShowIn=GNOME` to `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;`
- Remove the `StartupNotify=true` line

Save and restart the session.

Answer (score 1):

gnome-session dying because no compiz? I've seen this, have a look in /var/log/syslog for anything suspicious.
I solved it on a 4 screen, 2 nvidia card rig by hand editing the xorg.conf so that

Option "Composite" "Enabled"

Then I could use gnome-flashback without 3D effects and everything started ok.
Weird bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well, using gnome-flashback with compiz in Ubuntu 14.04.
To make gnome-panel start automatically on login, I did:

cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-panel.desktop ~/.config/autostart/